# Many views, one form, different validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

I have a couple of jsp pages, all of each use one form.

```
-------------------page1--------------------------
    <form:form modelAttribute="form" >
       <form:errors path="field1" class="error"/>
       <form:input path="field1" type="text"/>
    <form:form/>
-------------------page2--------------------------    
    <form:form modelAttribute="form" >
       <form:errors path="field2" class="error"/>
       <form:input path="field2" type="text"/>
    <form:form/>
-------------------page3--------------------------
    <form:form modelAttribute="form" >
       <form:errors path="field1" class="error"/>
       <form:input path="field1" type="text"/>
       <form:errors path="field2" class="error"/>
       <form:input path="field2" type="text"/>
    <form:form/>
```

And the form looks like

```
class Form{
   @NotBlank
   private String field1;
   @NotBlank
   private String field2;
   ...
}
```

My goals is implement validation for all this stuff. So, for first page **field1** is required but **field2** not. In the last one all fields are required.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. If in jsp is not field1, filed1 in Form is null. If is in jsp and user not fill it, in Form is filed1 empty string.

So I make custom anotation @NotEmptyString.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotEmptyStringValidator.class)
@Target({  FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface NotEmptyString {
    String message() default "{validation.notEmptyString}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}


public class NotEmptyStringValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmptyString, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(NotEmptyString annotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        return value == null || !value.isEmpty();
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `@InitBinder` and it's `setValidator()` method?

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder( WebDataBinder binder )
{
    binder.setValidator( new ValidatorForPage1() );
}
```

Where your `ValidatorForPage1` should implement `org.springframework.validation.Validator`. In this case, you have per Controller validation rules.